# Spring JPA Datasource Crash Recovery and Dynamic Changes on runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi I use spring jpa and as I understand its working mechanism truely it created at once in a singleton way.

Is it possible to change or recreate datasource on running environment.Scenario like this,Mypassword changed and if I wont stop application that time all my calls take exception.I have a mechanism to check password and change it dynamically and my others request get new password create new datasource and keep on working.

And another question is I have multiple datasource,at the application start if one of this datasource get exception that time my application cannot start.What I want if one of datasource not working ,application can continue to warmup and try to check creating datasource each related request.

I dont want to create persistencejpaconfig each request but I want to makes changes on datasource in every request if it is neccessary

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig{

....

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("********");
    dataSource.setUrl("*********");
    dataSource.setUsername( "**********" );
    dataSource.setPassword( "********" );
    return dataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement your own `DataSource` that delegates to the real `DataSource` and creates a new one when the password changes.

[`DelegatingDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DelegatingDataSource.html) might be of help, either as a basis class or, since you are going to change the `DataSource` as a template for an implementation.