# Why creation of repository beans need a datasource bean during start-up

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I was working on a Spring-data-jpa project with spring boot, I see that the creation of repository beans required a datasoure bean to be present, Why is it so?

And can a repository bean be created without datasource bean.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a repository is to load and save data into a persistent store.
Spring Data JPA does that using JPA so it needs an `EntityManager` which in turn need a `DataSource`.

Strictly speaking the `DataSource` is only used once the database is actually accessed. 
While you definitely nee a `DataSource` bean you may delay the construction of a normal `DataSource` by providing a wrapper which instantiates the the actual `DataSource` at a later point in time.

[`DelegatingDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DelegatingDataSource.html) might be of help, either as a basis class or, since you are going to change the `DataSource` as a template for an implementation.

See the somewhat related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208585/66686